# Electron WebAssembly: TypeError: Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'

Tags: javascript, electron, webassembly

WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming fails when using a local relative path. Is there any way to disable this check or does anyone have any advice on another approach of getting around the problem? I'm trying to remove having the dependency of a web backend of my electron project.

```js
<script>
    WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("relative/path/to/file.wasm", {
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/wasm"
        }
    }), {}).then(output => {
        console.log(output);
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used XMLHTTPRequest instead to get around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `fetch()` as long as you switch to using `instantiate()` instead of `instantiateStreaming()`, since the former does not care about MIME types, while the latter [does](https://www.w3.org/TR/wasm-web-api-1/#streaming-modules). Example:

```
const response = await fetch("relative/path/to/file.wasm");
const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const output = await WebAssembly.instantiate(buffer);
console.log(output);
```